i want to setup new connection but when i tried to run a script there is error showing access denied
i wanted to setup new connection i did also but when i try to run script it wont run there is error showing access denied
DROP USER 'newuser2'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'newuser2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '*********';
ALTER USER 'newuser2'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON IMDB+dataset+import(1).* TO 'newuser2'@'localhost';
i tried this but then too showing error access denied
